# Django url regexp not working

Tags: regex, django

I'm trying to get my head around regexp in Django urls.  I'm currently developing locally and I want to be able to direct a request such as `http://localhost:8000/options/items/item-string-1121/` to the 'details' view in my app called 'options', passing in the final number part of the request string (1121) as a parameter 'id' to the view function.

The signature for details in `options/views.py` is as follows, taking id=1 as default:

```
def details(request, id=1):
    ...
```

I have the following in my root urls.py:

```
...

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^options/, include(options.urls')),
)
```

and in options/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('options.views', 
    url(r'^items/(.+)(P<id>\d+)/$', 'details'),
    ...
)
```

Now when I try to request the above URL the dev server says it tried to match against the pattern `^options/ ^items/(.+)(P<id>\d+)/$` but it doesn't match.

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: There is not need to capture unnamed group, `r'^items/.+-(?P<id>\d+)/$'` is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a non-greedy quantifier on the (.+), so r'^items/(.+?)(P\d+)/$'. Otherwise that first glob happily eats until the end of the string, preventing the ID from ever matching.

Comment: Makes sense, but it's still not matching.. I just get a 404

Comment: Ahh, and that should also be (?P<id>), thats the more important one :-)

Comment: ok, that got it.. not sure what that second ? is for but thanks! :)

Comment: (?P<name>...) marks a named capture, in general most special types of capture groups start with (?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^options/, include(options.urls')),
)
```

Should be

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^options/', include('options.urls')),
)
```

I'm not too sure of your expression, might try this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('options.views', 
    url(r'^items/(?<=-)(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'details'),
    ...
)
```

Comment: The part between `/` and `(?P...)` does not get matched hence no match for whole